# Need help creating SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have thus two tables:

```
 CREATE TABLE `workers` (
  `id` int(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `number` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `percent` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `order` int(7) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 );
 CREATE `data` (
  `id` bigint(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `workerId` int(7) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 );
```

I want to return the first worker (order by `order` ASC) that his number of rows in the table `data` times `percent`(from table `workers`) /100 is smaller than `number`(from table `workers`.

I have tried this query:

```
SELECT workers.id, COUNT(data.id) AS `countOfData`
FROM `workers` as workers, `data` as data
WHERE data.workerId = workers.id
   AND workers.percent * `countOfData` < workers.number
LIMIT 1
```

But I get the error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'countOfData' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: Erm, if this is not mysql, please tag it with the appropriate rdbms.

Comment: You should not have `order` as a column name as it is a keyword in most of the SQL's.

Comment: it is mysql.... Juniad - ignore the name - let's call it `sortOrder` -

Comment: @Nir Next time tag it mysql then.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  If you have attempted the query yourself, it is always good to show your current thoughts/effort.  People are more likely to assist you if they can see you've put forth effort and have made an attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT A.id
FROM workers A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT workerId, COUNT(*) AS Quant
            FROM data
            GROUP BY workerId) B
ON A.id = B.workerId
WHERE (COALESCE(Quant,0) * `percent`)/100 < `number`
ORDER BY `order`
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks - it's work ok.. but if the worker in `order` 1 have no records on the `data` table, the query should retuen him. But it returned empty result

Comment: @Nir - I updated my answer to take your issue into account. I also deleted the `DESC` on the `ORDER` clause

Comment: By the way, i had a little mistake..
I whanted it to be WHERE COALESCE(Quant,0) * `number` < (`percent`)/100

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the number of rows per worker in a subquery.  The subquery can be joined to the worker table.  If you use a `left join`, a worker with no data rows will be considered:

```
select  *
from    workers w
left join    
        (
        select  workerId
        ,       count(*) as cnt
        from    data
        group by
                workerId
        ) d
on      w.id = d.workerId
where   coalesce(d.cnt, 0) * w.percent / 100 < w.number
order by
        w.order
limit   1
```

Comment: Thanks - it's work ok.. but if the worker in `order` 1 have no records on the data table, the query should retuen him. But it returned empty result

Comment: Updated the answer so it should return a worker with no records in the data table